# how do i make a stack out of a linked list?

Tags: java

I'm trying to create a Stack to take a string and add each of the strings characters to it, but I was told it would be far more efficient use a LinkedList. How would I use a LinkedList to create and manipulate a stack?

An example would be very appreciated!

Comment: Far more efficient? Why?

Comment: @Thilo because when I do "Stack<char>",  I keep getting errors.

Comment: Re: keep getting errors? How do you know the code is not efficient when it does not even work?

Comment: Apparently it's pretty much always more efficient to use an `ArrayList` actually. Also, [what have you tried](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com)?

Comment: @Jay You cannot use primitive types (char, int, ect.) in generics. Try `Stack<Character>`.

Comment: @Jeff I tried creating a linked list and creating my own methods for push(), pop() and empty(), however I had no luck. So I was hoping someone more experience could show me how.

Comment: @ValekHalfHeart I've tried that, however I keep getting the "Type Stack does not take parameters" error.

Comment: @Jay In that case you'll get a better welcome at SO if you post the code that you tried.

Comment: @Jeff should I just edit my original question with the code?

Comment: @Jay Yup. That way people can explain what misunderstandings you have, without having to guess :) edit: be warned though - this question may well wind up being closed anyway.

Comment: @Jeff that's fine, this website isn't very friendly to beginners in general.

Comment: @Jay What version of java are you running?

Comment: And what is the error that you're getting with this code?

Comment: @Jay That is very odd then, because I wrote a program in java 7 just yesterday that used a parameterized Stack.

Comment: @Jeff I'm not getting an error with this code, however it isn't producing the results I would like.

Comment: @ValekHalfHeart hmmm ... I wonder what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: @Jeff I would like the code to write the word "Dad" backwards, however I am getting no output from it at all.

Comment: See my answer - picked up on the problem right away :) Always always always post your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, the problem is that you're not using `First` at all. Try the following:

```
public class Example
{
    private LinkedList aList = new LinkedList();

    public void push(char c) {
        aList.addFirst(c);
    }
    public Object pop() {
        return aList.removeFirst();
    }
    public boolean empty() {
        return aList.isEmpty();
    }
    public static void main(String[] args)  {
        Stack exmpStack = new Stack();
        String ranString = "Dad";
        for (int i = 0; i < ranString.length(); i++)  {
            exmpStack.push(ranString.charAt(i));
        }
        while (!exmpStack.empty())  {
            System.out.print(exmpStack.pop());
        }
    }
}
```

Because you never use `First` it's always `null` - so your loop never runs at all! Instead of using that at all, just use the build in `isEmpty()` function.

**Edit:** Of course, you don't really need those functions at all - the following will work fine:

```
public class Example
{
    private LinkedList aList = new LinkedList();

    public static void main(String[] args)  {
        String ranString = "Dad";
        for (int i = 0; i < ranString.length(); i++)  {
            aList.push(ranString.charAt(i));
        }
        while (!aList.isEmpty())  {
            System.out.print(aList.pop());
        }
    }
}
```

Now this is still a bit unsafe - you can go one step further by using the following:

```
private LinkedList<Character> aList = new LinkedList<>();
```

That way it's a bit safer, and returns `Character`s instead of `Objects` - and `Characters` can be implicitly cast to `char` :)

Comment: You might want to get rid of exmpStack from your second example.

Comment: @DavidConrad Right you are - thanks

Answer (score 0):

Java's LinkedList is a doubly linked list, with efficient accessors to get, add, and remove elements both at the end and at the head of the list, so you can use those methods to emulate a stack.

Comment: could you provide an example? I'm not sure what the code would look like

Answer (score 0):

`LinkedList` is indeed more efficient, as `Stack` comes with synchronized methods by virtue of its reliance on `Vector`. In single-threaded applications, using the latter means paying the synchronization price for no benefit. Even in multi-threaded applications, you may want more control over synchronization.

Here's a possible LinkedList based solution. Please note the use of composition instead of inheritance. This will give you a well behaved Stack that cannot be abused by using List-related methods.

```
class MyStack<T> {
    private List<T> list = new LinkedList<T>();

    public void push(T object) { list.add(0, object); }

    public T pop(T object) {
        if (isEmpty()) throw new NoSuchElementException();
        return list.remove(0);
    }

    public boolean isEmpty() { return list.isEmpty(); }
}
```

Nonetheless, if your stack is meant only for string characters as your question suggests, you might want to emulate a stack directly on a dynamic character array. I will leave that as an exercise to the reader, or I may provide it in a future edit.

Comment: It looks like I gave an advanced answer for what looks like homework. Thanks for the -1, buddy!

Comment: that wasn't me who gave you the -1, I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

A LinkedList provides more operations that that of a stack.

You use a stack for pushing and popping your characters of your string. However you can only retrieve the character in the order that opposite the way you insert your string. So are you sure if you want this behaviour.

A linkedlist allows you to add/retrieve your data either from head / tail.

Comment: yeah I'm aware of that and I am ok with it.

Comment: I would argue that, if a stack is required, then a stack should be provided to uphold the principle of encapsulation. To provide list methods in a stack invites errors, as a stack can be compromised if bypassing its usual contract.

Comment: @MihaiDanila you are right. I misunderstood the question

Answer (score 0):

Here is the sample: [Stack implementation](http://www.firatatagun.com/stack-with-linkedlist-implementation/). Hope it helps.

It is done with C# but you get the idea

Comment: That confused me a little .... but I appreciate the input!

Comment: what is confusing ? the idea is you always add T as first and always remove first node from linkedlist